# Como tokenizar palavras em português utilizando NLTK?

Tags: python-3.x, natural-language

Estou tendo sérias dificuldades para entender esse mecanismo.

Em inglês seria apenas:

```
import nltk
tag_word = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
```

Sendo que `text` é o texto em inglês que eu gostaria de "*tokenizar*", o que ocorre muito bem, porém em português ainda não consegui achar nenhum exemplo.
Estou desconsiderando aqui as etapas anteriores de `stop_words` e `sent_tokenizer`, só para deixar claro que a minha dúvida é com relação a *tokenização*.

Comment: Já leu este [artigo](http://www.nltk.org/howto/portuguese_en.html) ou viu este [repositório](https://github.com/fmaruki/Nltk-Tagger-Portuguese)?

Comment: Ola @AndersonCarlosWoss, sim já li, mas ainda não consegui entender o fluxo. Consegui usar o stop_words com nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('portuguese'), mas ainda não consegui taggear as palavras, esse exemplo da internet achei muito pouco didático.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import nltk    
from nltk import tokenize    
palavras_tokenize = tokenize.word_tokenize(text, language='portuguese')
```

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se funcionaria há 5 anos atrás, mas resposta anterior não resolve a questão sobre tokenizar palavras em Português propriamente.  O `word_tokenize` usa o parâmetro `language` apenas para tokenizar sentenças internamente com o `PunktSentenceTokenizer` e a seguir tokenizar as palavras de cada sentença com o `NLTKWordTokenizer` e este último não oferece suporte a idiomas e possui tratamento de **contrações** e **elisão de sons ou supressão de letras** de forma *hardcoded* para o Inglês.

Se usarem `word_tokenize` para Português a tokenização funcionará bem para **pontuações, parênteses, colchetes e "<>"** mas falhará com termos como "d'água" entre outros, além do fato de que tratará contrações (e.g. wanna) em inglês quando não deveria, já que o idioma-alvo é Português e "wanna" seria no máximo um *nome próprio*.

A solução "temporária" que adotei foi usar `RegexpTokenizer` no lugar de `NLTKWordTokenizer`, customizando a função `word_tokenize` [original](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/a2af434efdd1e4c587ae659a8918212a8bf8edd5/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L114):

```
def my_word_tokenize(text, language="english", preserve_line=False):
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    return [for sent in sentences for token in RegexpTokenizer(r'(?u)\b\w+\b').tokenize(sent)
]
```

Próximos passos (que aprecio ajuda):

1. Customizar `nltk.tokenize.destructive.NLTKWordTokenizer`, basicamente a classe `MacIntyreContractions` e as listas `STARTING_QUOTES` e `ENDING_QUOTES`  para que possa tratar contrações e elisões também em **Português**, substituindo a função `my_word_tokenize` acima.
2. Retreinar o modelo de abreviações em portuguẽs do `PunktSentenceTokenizer` que vem pre-treinado em arquivo pickle do nltk para adotar as abreviações especificas para cada domínio.